# PHP forgot password not working

Tags: php

I am creating a forgot password page for my users but it's not working . I am following a tutorial and when the person doing the tutorial does something that works for them it doesn't work for me . For example , the queries don't search to see if the username and email exists . When I click submit , the page just refreshes and that's it , I don't get any emails of anything . Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong ?

forgotpass.php :

```
include("connect.php");

GLOBAL $email;
GLOBAL $submit;

if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
echo"fill in username to sign up";
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
echo"fill in email to sign up";
}   

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["username"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);

    $query = mysqli_query($conn ,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'");
    $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($numrow != 0 ){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $db_email = $row ['email'];
        }

        if($email == $db_email){

            $code = rand(10000, 1000000);

            $to = $db_email;
            $subject = "Password reset";
            $body = "
            This is an automated email. Please DO NOT reply to this email.
            Click the link below or paste it in your browser.
            http://localhost/testsocialnetwork/forgotpass.php?email=brandont264%40gmail.com&submit=Submit?code=$code&username=$username
            ";  

            mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET passreset='$code' WHERE username='" . $username . "'");

            mail($to, $subject, $body);

            echo"Check your email";

        } else{
            echo"email is incorrect";
        }

    }   else {
        echo"That username doesn't exists.";
    }   
}
```

form:

```
<form>
<center><p id="p1">Your E-mail: <input size="30" type="text" name="email" />   </p>
<center><p id="p1">Your username: <input size="30" type="text" name="username" /></p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</center>
</form>
```

UPDATE !!!

`Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()`

I got this error and to be perfectly honest with everyone trying to help me ... I have zero idea what it means . Can I get help with it ?

Comment: You should not have a space between $row and ['email'] in `$db_email = $row ['email'];`. If that is not the immediate problem, add the code for the form.

Comment: I just added the form code

Comment: You have no `action` attribute on the `<form>` tag so it will be submitted to the same page the form appears on. If that is not what you want, you need to add something like `action="forgotpass.php"` to the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Your updated problem with `mail` now is a different issue - with your php configuration. You should probably ask about that separately.